# Posting questions on ServerFault seems not to work in Opera

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've just tried asking a question (well, I've just tried asking it again, as the first attempt didn't seem to "take", I probably pressed the [Post Your Question] button and closed the tab) and it seems as if clicking on the [Post Your Question] tab doesn't work.

I seem to be able to post this question on meta.serverfault. I have successfully posted a question on StackOverflow, using this browser, back in February.

The "main" symptom is that the button appears slightly grayed out and clicking on it does nothing. Is is just a question of asking a "longer" question?

*Edit*: I have now tried posting from Iceape and taht seemed to work fine, so the immediate worry is over. However, I suspect it would be good to know if this is a problem on the Opera side or if it's site-dependent.

Comment: Opera Mini, or Opera Mobile, or Opera "normal"? There are a *lot* of known issues with Opera Mini which the Stack Exchange team won't/can't fix because of its unique rendering method.

Comment: Opera "Normal". I managed to use the same browser (possibly even the very same process) to post a question to SO in February, so I know it has worked, in the past.

Comment: How many characters were in the question you were unable to post?

Comment: About 650 characters. POsting the exact same body with Iceape worked just fine.

Comment: @Vatine: is this still a problem ?

Comment: Iain: I can check when I get home. I don't post that many questions and I am pretty sure that I've been able to post answers in Opera at all times. All I need now is a suitable question...

Comment: @Vatine: you could always just post a test question and then delete it

Comment: @Iain True. I'll try to get it tested tonight.

Comment: @Vatine: fixed ?

Comment: Iain: Seems to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed.

Comment: It has. I was posting with Opera all along.